# Multi-language global/custom Exception handling in .NET Core 2.1 Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, exception, multilingual

I'm currently adding some middlewares on my **.NET Core 2.1 Web API** project to integrate *multi-language support* and a **"as much as possible"** REST/RFC compliant *Exception handling mechanism*.

About multi-language, I started with the built-in `IStringLocalizer<T>` class,  Localization middleware and service registration inside the `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods in `Startup` class and then creating the culture' specific RESX files.

For Exception handling, I also used the `app.UseExceptionHandler()` built-in middleware as follows:

```
public static class ExceptionHandler
{
    public static void UseGlobalExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(config =>
        {
            config.Run(async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                var errorFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if (errorFeature != null)
                {
                    Exception ex = errorFeature.Error;
                    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails
                    {
                        StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                        Message = ex.Message
                    };

                    Log.Error(ex, "Request error {ErrorDetails}", errorDetails);
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(errorDetails.ToString());
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to make the multi-language support and the Exception handling work together, to customize the language of the error details text.

Is there a best practice or a "standard" well known approach with those built-in .NET Core objects?

Also some side questions:

1. I didn't actually really understand what's the difference (the benefits) between built-in global Exception handling and the possibility to create a custom Exception middleware.
2. About RFC compliance on Exception handling, I red [this article](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/07/centralized-exception-handling-and-request-validation-in-asp-net-core/). Should I use the built-in `ProblemDetails` .NET Core object or can I use my `ErrorDetails` class as well?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?